# Is it possible to customize a removable drive launcher/quicklist?

Tags: unity, quicklists

So, I do know that it is fairly easy to customize application shortcuts (launchers) by editing the respective .desktop file. But, is it possible to create custom quicklists to the removable drives' launchers? E.g. a "Format" option or "Properties" would be really useful.

Comment: Even I am interested to know this, especially accessing mountable NTFS partitions in internal hard drive.

Comment: Very good Question

Comment: I agree it is a good question (made it 10 just now ;) ) but everything in /media seems to be added without a .desktop file. So there is a high probability it is hard coded (did not find any evidence of that either though).

Answer (score 6):

This is currently not possible because the menu items are hardcoded.

However, if you think that feature should be discussed, you can write a mail to the [Ayatana mailing list](https://launchpad.net/ayatana) and elaborate on why it should be included. :)

Comment: dead link - would have been better to have copied the relevant information here as well

Comment: How would source code from a year ago have helped you **now**?

Comment: It would give an indication of where to look to see if any changes have been made that would help solve this question

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. The pinning of the drives icon in the launcher isn't controlled by a .desktop file. It is added as UUID of the drive/partition. You can check this by using the command

```
 $ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Devices favorites 
 ['A80C1BD70C1B9F7E']
```

And for your information, In Unity version 5.14.0 (Ubuntu 12.04) there is an option named *Format* too. but no option with *Properties* though.